# Broadcast receiver for gtalk/gmail message receive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

It is easy to find on google which is the broadcast receiver to listen for sms messages. Is there also a similar receiver to listen for gtalk messages or new emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those applications are part of the SDK, so there are no documented broadcast `Intents` for either action -- sorry!