# Android Register for GTalk Incoming Chat

Tags: android, xmpp, google-talk

Is there a server to register for to get Google Talk incoming messages pushed to the phone? Is there a server to manually check for new messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the SmackApi for Android. I connect to Google Talk's servers and register to get incoming messages. Works exactly as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412393/broadcast-receiver-for-gtalk-gmail-message-receive) SO question:

Matroska:

> It is easy to find on google which is the broadcast receiver to listen for sms messages. Is there also a similar receiver to listen for gtalk messages or new emails?
>   Thanks

CommonsWare:

> Neither of those applications are part of the SDK, so there are no documented broadcast Intents for either action -- sorry!